# Pin panel open in XAML designer

Tags: wpf, xaml

ComboBox lets you pin it open in the designer, so you can design its contents:

[image]

Anyone know if there's a way to do similar in a control I write? I'd like a control containing a ToggleButton that shows/hides a panel in the control, and for consumers of the control to be able to pin it open in the designer.

Comment: I'm not sure how you make it appear in the context menu like that, but I would imagine you could just do something like `d:AttachedProperty="bool"` so the designer would just leave it invoked. Good question though either way.